# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have never used JavaScript or CSS before. I have used Actionscript and I find it similar to JavaScript.

I am making a small html page where there is a fadeInUp animation from animation.css

I wanted to do the animation myself, instead of animation.css doing it for me, for practice.

I did everything right, except the animation does not stay at the end opacity, it resets to the css-coded opacity.

I decided to do some javascripting and made this code

(the div that the two animated elements are in is called "toppart")

```
var beginpart = document.getElementById("toppart");
beginpart.addEventListener("animationend", giveopac, false);
function giveopac()
{
this.style.opacity=1
}
```

I do not know what is wrong with it (probably something wrong with syntax), but I get this console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
(anonymous function)
```

Is the problem with the function or is it with variable? If something is wrong with the event listener, there are about 10 websites that are wrong.

If anybody knows what I am doing wrong, and why it is giving me the error, I would love to know.

Comment: Can you provide the markup too ...Just check if there is any element toppart

Comment: This line causing you the problem `var beginpart = document.getElementById("toppart");` may be element with id `toppart` not exists on dom

Comment: Gotta make sure there's a `div` with an `id` attribute of `"toppart"`

Comment: May be you need to fire this on page load, might be you placed this code before the element in dom;

Comment: @Geeky <body>
<div id="toppart">
<p id="first" class="moveupfade">Zane Clark</p>
<p id="subfirst" class="moveupfade">"Keter"</p>
</div>
</body> This is the whole body, I don't know what a markup is........

Comment: Is it still not working?

Comment: It is likely that your JavaScript runs before `body` contents are loaded. Try putting your scripts at the end of your markup.

Comment: @JohnWhite That didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

I put it after the whole body and changed it to this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("toppart").addEventListener("animationend", giveopac);
function giveopac(event)
{
event.target.style.opacity=1;
}
</script>
```

Thanks to geeky

Answer (score 0):

If it is still not working it is because in the giveopac event you are trying to access this and adding style to it which is not right.Here this is window object
You might consider changing this
check the following code snippet

```js
var beginpart = document.getElementById("toppart");
 // alert(beginpart);
beginpart.addEventListener("animationend", giveopac, false);
function giveopac(event)
{

event.target.style.opacity=1;
event.target.style.background="red";
}
```

```html
<body> 
  <div id="toppart"> 
  <p id="first" class="moveupfade">Zane Clark</p> 
  <p id="subfirst" class="moveupfade">"Keter"</p> 
  </div> 
</body>
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: Would I replace event with anything (I don't use JavaScript, sorry that I dont know)? If not, it does not, it may not work :(

Comment: ya it does not object because event is the object that which is always passed and will be available on the handler..for more information you can read it here http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have your script tags before closing tag of body in html page.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="toppart"> <p id="first" class="moveupfade">Zane Clark</p> <p id="subfirst" 
class="moveupfade">"Keter"</p> </div> 
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```